# AVD shows black screen with image built from AOSP without any change

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I've being struggling with android emulator for three days now.

What I have done:

1. Repo sync to get latest changes.
2. Source build/envsetup to set up the environment
3. lunch to select aosp_x86_64-eng target
4. make -j16
5. emulator -verbose -no-accel

That's my out:

```
rodrigof@SOL-UBUNTU-RODRIGOF:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ emulator -no-accel -verbose
emulator:Android emulator version 25.3.0.0 (build_id 3700138)
emulator:Found ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT: /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64
emulator:Found build target architecture: x86_64
emulator:argv[0]: 'emulator'; program directory: '/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64'
emulator:try dir /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64
emulator:Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
emulator:Adding library search path: '/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_angle'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/libstdc++'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Running :/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-no-accel"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -no-accel -verbose
emulator: found Android build root: /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY
emulator: found Android build out:  /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64
emulator: Read property file at /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system/build.prop
emulator: Cannot find boot properties file: /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/boot.prop

emulator: Found target API sdkVersion: 26

emulator: Invalid int property: 'ro.build.version.incremental:eng.rodrig.20190430.121425'
emulator: virtual device has no config file - no problem
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/development/tools/emulator/skins//HVGA/hardware.ini
emulator: autoconfig: -skin HVGA
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/development/tools/emulator/skins/
emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/development/tools/emulator/skins//HVGA/hardware.ini
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86_64/ranchu/kernel-qemu
emulator: Target arch = 'x86_64'
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/ramdisk.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sysdir /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64
emulator: Using initial system image: /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system.img
emulator: WARNING: system partition size adjusted to match image file (2560 MB > 200 MB)

emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/userdata.img
emulator: WARNING: data partition size adjusted to match image file (550 MB > 200 MB)

emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/cache.img
emulator: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
emulator: VM heap size 48MB is below hardware specified minimum of 192MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 127.0.1.1
emulator: trying to load skin file '/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/development/tools/emulator/skins//HVGA/layout'
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working, but disabled by user
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
emulator: WARNING: x86_64 emulation may not work without hardware acceleration!
sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator: Using default value for kernel Contiguous Memory Allocation.
emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 127.0.1.1
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86_64
  hw.cpu.ncore = 2
  hw.ramSize = 1024
  hw.screen = multi-touch
  hw.mainKeys = true
  hw.trackBall = true
  hw.keyboard = false
  hw.keyboard.lid = false
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = true
  hw.rotaryInput = false
  hw.gsmModem = true
  hw.gps = true
  hw.battery = true
  hw.accelerometer = true
  hw.audioInput = true
  hw.audioOutput = true
  hw.sdCard = true
  disk.cachePartition = true
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 320
  hw.lcd.height = 480
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 160
  hw.lcd.backlight = true
  hw.gpu.enabled = true
  hw.gpu.mode = host
  hw.gpu.blacklisted = no
  hw.initialOrientation = portrait
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 192
  hw.sensors.light = true
  hw.sensors.pressure = true
  hw.sensors.humidity = true
  hw.sensors.proximity = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
  hw.sensors.orientation = true
  hw.sensors.temperature = true
  hw.useext4 = true
  kernel.path = /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86_64/ranchu/kernel-qemu
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 2560m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 550m
  avd.name = <build>
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
emulator: argv[01] = "-dns-server"
emulator: argv[02] = "127.0.1.1"
emulator: argv[03] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[04] = "null"
emulator: argv[05] = "-cpu"
emulator: argv[06] = "android64"
emulator: argv[07] = "-smp"
emulator: argv[08] = "cores=2"
emulator: argv[09] = "-m"
emulator: argv[10] = "1024"
emulator: argv[11] = "-lcd-density"
emulator: argv[12] = "160"
emulator: argv[13] = "-kernel"
emulator: argv[14] = "/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86_64/ranchu/kernel-qemu"
emulator: argv[15] = "-initrd"
emulator: argv[16] = "/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/ramdisk.img"
emulator: argv[17] = "-object"
emulator: argv[18] = "iothread,id=disk-iothread"
emulator: argv[19] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[20] = "if=none,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=0,id=system,file=/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system.img.qcow2,read-only"
emulator: argv[21] = "-device"
emulator: argv[22] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[23] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[24] = "if=none,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=1,id=cache,file=/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/cache.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[25] = "-device"
emulator: argv[26] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[27] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[28] = "if=none,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=2,id=userdata,file=/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[29] = "-device"
emulator: argv[30] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[31] = "-netdev"
emulator: argv[32] = "user,id=mynet"
emulator: argv[33] = "-device"
emulator: argv[34] = "virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet"
emulator: argv[35] = "-netdev"
emulator: argv[36] = "user,id=mynet2,net=10.0.3.0/24"
emulator: argv[37] = "-device"
emulator: argv[38] = "virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet2"
emulator: argv[39] = "-show-cursor"
emulator: argv[40] = "-L"
emulator: argv[41] = "/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib/pc-bios"
emulator: argv[42] = "-soundhw"
emulator: argv[43] = "hda"
emulator: argv[44] = "-vga"
emulator: argv[45] = "none"
emulator: argv[46] = "-append"
emulator: argv[47] = "qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=ranchu clocksource=pit android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1"
emulator: argv[48] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[49] = "/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -dns-server 127.0.1.1 -serial null -cpu android64 -smp cores=2 -m 1024 -lcd-density 160 -kernel /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86_64/ranchu/kernel-qemu -initrd /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/ramdisk.img -object iothread,id=disk-iothread -drive if=none,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=0,id=system,file=/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system.img.qcow2,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=1,id=cache,file=/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/cache.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,index=2,id=userdata,file=/home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -netdev user,id=mynet2,net=10.0.3.0/24 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet2 -show-cursor -L /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib/pc-bios -soundhw hda -vga none -append 'qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=ranchu clocksource=pit android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1' -android-hw /home/rodrigof/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '131072'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '192m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.adb.secure' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
emulator: goldfish_events.have-dpad: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-trackball: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-camera: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-keyboard: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-touch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-multitouch: true
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: WARNING: Ignoring invalid http proxy: Bad format: invalid port number (must be decimal)
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

emulator: Window was not fully visible: monitor=[0,0,1824,1026] window=[520,246,791,534]
emulator: Window repositioned to [516,246]
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

emulator: OpenGL Vendor=[Google (NVIDIA Corporation)]
emulator: OpenGL Renderer=[Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (GeForce GT 520/PCIe/SSE2)]
emulator: OpenGL Version=[OpenGL ES 2.0 (4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.130)]
emulator: onGuestSendCommand: [0x7f93a401b1f0] Adb connected, start proxing data
```

But no image is shown on AVD screen.

It is important to say that when running an emulator created by the AVD Manager using a downloaded x86-64 image, it runs with no problem.

Also, is I copy the built system.img to AVD emulator's folder and run it by AVDManager, it shows black screen too.

I've tried with several different targets (arm, x86, arm-eng....) and the result is the same: Device shows a black screen when using built image.

Does anyone have any clue about what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was probable checked on a unstable code review. After checking on a stable branch, I've rebuilt and use the "emulator" again. It worked.